# Is it possible opening windows control panel with a hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Is it possible to open the Control Panel (Windows) using a hyperlink on a webpage?  For example, I'd like to make something similar to Windows Help (but online), where an article could have a link to (say) the "Internet Connection Wizard".  It'd be great if this is possible to do.

Comment: That would imply that _all_ computers are running windows(which is not the case) and any script that runs within a browser has some control over what the client's OS is doing... I'd hope not...

Comment: Nope. And if it were implemented, I'd never go to your website.

Comment: The only way would be through ActiveX controls, which are Windows/IE-only. However a quick google search did not reveal anything useful. I suspect what you are asking is (rightly) impossible. You're browser should NEVER be able to open up such a core system feature as the Control Panel. Just think, if you can open it up with a script, you can probably change the items in it with a script. Scary stuff.

Comment: Inline code blocks are _not_ meant to be used for emphasis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's a good idea, but when using IE you can try this:

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="file:///C:/Windows/system32/control.exe">test</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But it opens download window to download the file and then a security warning. I want to open control panel directly.

Comment: I don't think that you can get any closer than that, except for perhaps some ActiveX magic...

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at clickonce - make a small application, that will open C:\Windows\system32\control.exe; that should work as long as you use IE and your end user have .NET installed on his machine.

Answer (score 0):

If the website is local only of course.
You can bring up the control panel and drag one of the choices from the control panel to the desktop.
Then right-click the desktop shortcut and select *properties and security*.
To the right of object name, you see the shortcut link.

Example: `C:\Users\{username}\Desktop\Personalize.lnk`